# Match two cells and copy from a third cell

Tags: excel-formula

I have a list of two names. One, the employee list, the other, a list of transfers.  I want to *match the names and then in an adjacent column post the new city*.

I am using the following and I realize that the `$X$1` will only post the first transfer city to all of the applicable names.

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(D1,$Q$1:$Q$159,0)),"",$X$1)
```

What can use to replace the `$X$1` ?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it's `=LOOKUP()` time:

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP($D1,$Q:$Q,$X:$X),"")
```

Assuming list of employees is in column `Q` and list of transfer cities is in column `X`.

Notes:

- `=IFERROR()` allows to simplify `=IF()` and `=ISERROR()` combo.
- You can pass the whole columns and rows to functions instead of fixed ranges. This is useful because you don't have to rewrite your formulae each time more data are added. `$Q:$Q` means whole column `Q`, `1:1` means whole row `1` etc.
- It's a good practice to fix the column of parameters, even if you don't plan to copy your formula to another column: `$D1`.